# Selection sort method seems to do nothing

Tags: c++, arrays, class, sorting, selection-sort

I'm working on a deck class, comprised of an array of card objects. One of the methods I have to write for this deck class is a sort method, which should sort the cards by number, ending in an array of cards in the order: 1s of each suit, 2s of each suit, 3s of each suit, and so on.
With this card class,

```
class card {
public:
    int number;
    string suit;
    card() {number = 1;suit = "blank";}
    card(int n, string s) {number = n; suit = s;}

    void printCard() {
        cout << number << " of " << suit << "s";
    }
};
```

I'm trying to implement a method for the deck class that uses selection sort to sort the array.

This is my code for my method sort(), declared and defined within the deck class:

```
void sort() {
    int min, j;
    for(int i=0;i<numCards-1;i++) {
        min = i;
        for(j=i+1;j<numCards;j++) {
            if(cardArray[i].number < cardArray[min].number)
                min = j;
        }
        if(min != i)
            swapCards(cardArray[i], cardArray[min]);
    }
}

void swapCards(card &a, card &b) {
    card temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

However, when I call it on a deck object d, nothing seems to happen. I've written some other methods that shuffle the deck or cut the deck and swap each half, both of which work, but when I call sort(), nothing happens. I've been checking the array through a printCards() method and it changes when I call shuffle() or cut(), but stays the same as the previous printout after I call sort().

In main():

```
deck d;

d.printDeck();
cout << endl;
d.shuffle();
d.printDeck();
cout << endl;
d.sort();
d.printDeck();
```

Printout after debugging:

```
1 of hearts
2 of hearts
3 of hearts
4 of hearts
5 of hearts
6 of hearts
7 of hearts
8 of hearts
9 of hearts
10 of hearts
11 of hearts
12 of hearts
13 of hearts
1 of clubs
2 of clubs
3 of clubs
4 of clubs
5 of clubs
6 of clubs
7 of clubs
8 of clubs
9 of clubs
10 of clubs
11 of clubs
12 of clubs
13 of clubs
1 of spades
2 of spades
3 of spades
4 of spades
5 of spades
6 of spades
7 of spades
8 of spades
9 of spades
10 of spades
11 of spades
12 of spades
13 of spades
1 of diamonds
2 of diamonds
3 of diamonds
4 of diamonds
5 of diamonds
6 of diamonds
7 of diamonds
8 of diamonds
9 of diamonds
10 of diamonds
11 of diamonds
12 of diamonds
13 of diamonds

7 of diamonds
6 of spades
5 of diamonds
12 of clubs
2 of diamonds
5 of spades
8 of diamonds
4 of clubs
1 of hearts
8 of clubs
10 of hearts
13 of diamonds
11 of diamonds
12 of spades
2 of hearts
3 of spades
12 of diamonds
7 of spades
11 of hearts
5 of clubs
5 of hearts
1 of spades
10 of diamonds
7 of clubs
4 of diamonds
3 of diamonds
13 of spades
13 of hearts
12 of hearts
6 of clubs
1 of diamonds
11 of spades
9 of hearts
3 of hearts
9 of diamonds
9 of clubs
10 of clubs
10 of spades
9 of spades
2 of spades
6 of hearts
8 of spades
4 of hearts
1 of clubs
11 of clubs
4 of spades
3 of clubs
2 of clubs
6 of diamonds
8 of hearts
13 of clubs
7 of hearts

7 of diamonds
6 of spades
5 of diamonds
12 of clubs
2 of diamonds
5 of spades
8 of diamonds
4 of clubs
1 of hearts
8 of clubs
10 of hearts
13 of diamonds
11 of diamonds
12 of spades
2 of hearts
3 of spades
12 of diamonds
7 of spades
11 of hearts
5 of clubs
5 of hearts
1 of spades
10 of diamonds
7 of clubs
4 of diamonds
3 of diamonds
13 of spades
13 of hearts
12 of hearts
6 of clubs
1 of diamonds
11 of spades
9 of hearts
3 of hearts
9 of diamonds
9 of clubs
10 of clubs
10 of spades
9 of spades
2 of spades
6 of hearts
8 of spades
4 of hearts
1 of clubs
11 of clubs
4 of spades
3 of clubs
2 of clubs
6 of diamonds
8 of hearts
13 of clubs
7 of hearts
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I don't have much of an idea as to why nothing seems to happen to the array, considering I've successfully implemented selection sort for other projects involving arrays and classes. The only new-ish thing I'm doing here is sorting an array of objects with multiple variables, but I'm pretty sure I'm comparing the proper variable between each card in sort().

If anyone sees a glaring mistake or has an idea of what might be causing this problem, please let me know. It'd go a long way to helping me solve this problem.

Edit: Added code for other methods used in deck class and debug output.

Comment: Please post all the related code (e.g. how the how the `swapCards` is defined, and what is `numCards`). Also, why not to add debug output in each sort iteration?

Comment: `if(cardArray[i].number < cardArray[min].number)`. I'm fairly sure you'd want to use `j` somehow in that comparison... (Also, unless you are doing something very special in `swapCards`, `std::swap` would work just fine.)

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use `std::sort`?

Comment: @user657267 The sort method is a required part of the class for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the selection of `min`:

```
for(j=i+1;j<numCards;j++) {
    if(cardArray[i].number < cardArray[min].number)
        min = j;
}
```

Throughout this loop, `min` doesn't change, so the `if` statement is meaningless. You probably mean to check `cardArray[j]` against the current minimum:

```
for(j=i+1;j<numCards;j++) {
    if(cardArray[j].number < cardArray[min].number)
        min = j;
}
```

Comment: That was it! Yes, with the way the loops were set up, I meant to check cardArray[j] vs the lowest so far. Thank you, guess I need to review my code a little more closely.